# Javascript: Array iteration works on the second expression but not on the first

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

So I am importing the following things from a mongoDB database, on a node.js app I'm building, the block sections I'm going to post are all inside an asynchronous function, I'll try to post a console log for each of the objects I'm working with to see if anyone can explain this to me, but basically **I have 2 array iterations, that build an object to be sent to the front-end as an array of objects, however the code sends the first object that matches my iterations and after that it returns a blank object**, meaning that if I try to add more than object to the expected output it will only return one of the first element that the expression finds and it does not check for the rest of them.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me with this!

The objects I'm working with:

```
const about = await About.find(); //always has one document only so no conflict here
const allSkills = await Skill.find(); //grabs all the skills in the database
const skills = about[0].skillBag.filter((name) => name); //selects all the skills the user saved
```

Console logs:

```
console.log(allSkills) -> [
  {
    _id: 5fa59424f3d6532ae63fad26,
    category: 'Web Development',
    name: 'wordpress',
    path: 'wordpress.svg',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 5fa5979c9e84032b92d3e9ee,
    category: 'DevOps',
    name: 'nginx',
    path: 'nginx.svg',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 5fa597b79e84032b92d3e9ef,
    category: 'Web Development',
    name: 'javascript',
    path: 'javascript.svg',
    __v: 0
  },
.
.
.
]

console.log(skills) -> ["javascript","nginx"]
```

Since I've been trying to debug this for a while now I've built even separated the expressions to try to iterate on one array at a time:

```
//This lists all the skills with the category 'DevOps' 
//and builds an object from them with the output {name: 'nginx', path: 'nginx.svg'}
const allDevOpsSkills = allSkills
      .filter((e) => e.category == "DevOps")
      .map((n) => ({ name: n.name, path: n.path }));
// Does the same for the category 'Web Development'
const allWebDevSkills = allSkills
      .filter((e) => e.category == "Web Development")
      .map((n) => ({ name: n.name, path: n.path }));
```

These 2 expressions always return an array with the objects **.map()** builds
Then I grab these 2 expressions and do:

```
const userDevOpsSkills = allDevOpsSkills.filter((n, i) => n.name == `${skills[i]}`);

// returns [ { name: 'nginx', path: 'nginx.svg' } ]

const userWebDevSkills = allWebDevSkills.filter((n, i) => n.name == `${skills[i]}`);

// returns [] and not [ { name: 'javascript', path: 'javascript.svg' } ]
```

I know I can do this in one expression instead of 2, that is the final version of my expressions however if I execute my code like the example above or if I run it like the example bellow the output is always the same

```
//Same expressions as above but in a more short way

    const userWebDevSkills = allSkills
      .filter((e) => e.category == "Web Development")
      .map((n) => ({ name: n.name, path: n.path }))
      .filter((n, i) => n.name == `${skills[i]}`);
    const userDevOpsSkills = allSkills
      .filter((e) => e.category == "DevOps")
      .map((n) => ({ name: n.name, path: n.path }))
      .filter((n, i) => n.name == `${skills[i]}`);
```

*Extra info:*

-The arguments that my current **skills** constant on the first code block returns are all stored in the database, but so that the post does not get any longer I redacted it, I want to do multiple checks on the same array.

I'm sorry if I can't explain myself any better, english is not my first language and I haven't been coding for that long to understand what exactly is going wrong in here.

Again thanks in advance to anyone that can help me with this!

**EDIT**
Bellow is the code without been split into individual code blocks

```
const express = require("express");
const About = require("../models/aboutSchema");
const Skill = require("../models/skillSchema");
const { logger } = require("../controllers/logs");

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const path = req.originalUrl;
    const about = await About.find();
    const allSkills = await Skill.find();
    const skills = about[0].skillBag.filter((name) => name);
    
    const userWebDevSkills = allSkills
      .filter((e) => e.category == "Web Development")
      .map((n) => ({ name: n.name, path: n.path }))
      .filter((n, i) => n.name == `${skills[i]}`);
    const userDevOpsSkills = allSkills
      .filter((e) => e.category == "DevOps")
      .map((n) => ({ name: n.name, path: n.path }))
      .filter((n, i) => n.name == `${skills[i]}`);

    console.log(userWebDevSkills);
    res.status(200).render("home.ejs", {
      title: "Homepage | FilipeDev",
      user: req.user,
      path,
      about: about[0],
      webDev: userWebDevSkills,
      devOps: userDevOpsSkills,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    logger.error(e);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I can't follow the actual problem in this question.  What is the input.  What is the expected output?  What is the observed output?

Comment: If you're getting an empty array when you expect values to be in there, a common reason for that is improper asynchronous code where you're trying to use the value before some asynchronous operation has fill it with the desired values.  But, you don't show any any asynchronous code (though there is a reference to database code being involved here) so there's nothing we can do to help with that possibility.  I'd suggest you show a full request handler here including all your database code.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm trying to build an object on the back-end to be able to send the filename for each skill I have stored on the aboutSchema so that I can render those files on the front-end, I've edited the post and posted the entire file in question for better understanding

Comment: I don't see any edits.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry forgot to save the edit, its edited now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are expecting:

```
const userWebDevSkills = allWebDevSkills.filter((n, i) => n.name == `${skills[i]}`);
```

to give you:

```
[ { name: 'javascript', path: 'javascript.svg' } ]
```

When I run this code:

```
const skills = ["javascript", "nginx"];

const allSkills = [{
        _id: 'fa59424f3d6532ae63fad26',
        category: 'Web Development',
        name: 'wordpress',
        path: 'wordpress.svg',
        __v: 0
    },
    {
        _id: 'fa5979c9e84032b92d3e9ee',
        category: 'DevOps',
        name: 'nginx',
        path: 'nginx.svg',
        __v: 0
    },
    {
        _id: 'fa597b79e84032b92d3e9ef',
        category: 'Web Development',
        name: 'javascript',
        path: 'javascript.svg',
        __v: 0
    },
];

const allDevOpsSkills = allSkills
    .filter((e) => e.category == "DevOps")
    .map((n) => ({ name: n.name, path: n.path }));

const allWebDevSkills = allSkills
    .filter((e) => e.category == "Web Development")
    .map((n) => ({ name: n.name, path: n.path }));

const userWebDevSkills = allWebDevSkills.filter((n, i) => n.name == `${skills[i]}`);
```

I do, indeed, get an empty array for userWebDevSkills and the issue is that `allWebDevSkills` ends up being this:

```
[
  { name: 'wordpress', path: 'wordpress.svg' },
  { name: 'javascript', path: 'javascript.svg' }
]
```

And, if `skills` is this:

```
["javascript","nginx"]
```

Then, this condition:

```
n.name == `${skills[i]}`
```

is never true so you never keep any items from the `allWebDevSkills.filter()` operation and thus end up with an empty array.  I don't know exactly what you're attempting to do with the

```
n.name == `${skills[i]}`
```

comparison so I'm' not sure exactly what to suggest to fix it, but this is demanding an exact position in the array match between `allWebDevSkills` and `skills` for the `.name` property and that doesn't happen.  The `javascript` name property is in position 1 of `allWebDevSkills`, but in position `0` for the `skills` array and thus will never match your filter condition.

---

Also, code like this:

```
 n.name == `${skills[i]}`
```

can just be this:

```
 n.name === skills[i]
```

There is no need to put a single string into a `${}` template by itself and `===` is favored when comparing strings (and not wanting to enable type conversion).

---

If what you're trying to do with the `.filter()` is to remove any items that don't have a `.name` property that is ANYWHERE in the `skills` array, then I would suggest this:

```js
    const skills = ["javascript", "nginx"];
    const skillsSet = new Set(skills);
    
    const allSkills = [{
            _id: 'fa59424f3d6532ae63fad26',
            category: 'Web Development',
            name: 'wordpress',
            path: 'wordpress.svg',
            __v: 0
        },
        {
            _id: 'fa5979c9e84032b92d3e9ee',
            category: 'DevOps',
            name: 'nginx',
            path: 'nginx.svg',
            __v: 0
        },
        {
            _id: 'fa597b79e84032b92d3e9ef',
            category: 'Web Development',
            name: 'javascript',
            path: 'javascript.svg',
            __v: 0
        },
    ];
    
    const allDevOpsSkills = allSkills
        .filter((e) => e.category == "DevOps")
        .map((n) => ({ name: n.name, path: n.path }));
    
    const allWebDevSkills = allSkills
        .filter((e) => e.category == "Web Development")
        .map((n) => ({ name: n.name, path: n.path }));
    
    const userWebDevSkills = allWebDevSkills.filter(n => skillsSet.has(n.name));
    
    console.log(userWebDevSkills);
```

Comment: With the expression ` n.name == `${skills[i]}` ` I am trying to filter all the items inside `allSkills` and checking if they are present in the `skills` item, and if they are I want them to be written to the `userWebDevSkills` if they belong to the category `Web Development`.
Both the `userWebDevSkills` and `userDevOpsSkills` should return an array of objects that can be iterated with an forEach on the front end with EJS.
However I'm not sure if this is how I should do this, hence the question.
Thanks for trying to help anyhow

Comment: @FilipeFigueiredo - So you want to remove items that don't have a name that matches ANY array item in the `skills` array?  If so, you should put the skills in a `Set` object and use the `skillsSet.has(n.name)` as your test.

Comment: @FilipeFigueiredo - I added that scenario to my answer.

Comment: that was it! changing the skills array into a Set an then filter to check if it `.has(n.name)` did the job. However I did not knew about this javascript functionality, after a little reading and understanding how Set works, I am now able to print all the images for each skill in `skills` on the front-end. I truly appreciate your help and patience to try to figure out what I was trying to ask

Comment: I've marked it as an correct answer, again thanks a lot for your help!